# Send user-specific information through sharepoint

Tags: permissions, user-profile, user-information-list

I have just recently started to use Sharepoint, so bare with me for my ignorance.
I have created a sharepoint site, where employees can submit information to our headquarter on customers. This is done through an InfoPath form which saves the information to a sharepoint-list. I have given the users access to only seeing their own contributions, since the information is highly classified. This is all fine and dandy.

My question, however, is: Is it possible for us in HQ to send out information to the specific employees, that only they will be able to see on sharepoint? Kind of similar to if they had submitted information, that only they (and admins) can see.
We want to send out customer-specific information to the individual employee; but since it is highly classified, no one else is supposed to see that information but the specific employee.
I was thinking that we could do some sort of list or something, where we specify which employee should be able to read the individual items/rows.

We have 1,000+ employees accessing this sharepoint site, so it needs to be fairly simple without too much manual labor.

Is this possible in any way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Below can be done,

One time activity....Write site workflow...
1. Write a workflow to read your Customers list, you will get createdby column which will give you employee to whom you send to send information.
2. Loop through each items and send email to each employees with instructions as required. you can also send Customer List data in your mail if required.

Now to continue sending this information on subsequent updates or entries which are created in customer list.

Write another List workflow which triggers on item add. As it is list workflow you will get List data in your workflow, just send email to user who created this item.... here we don't need to loop through each items as only one email has to be send when item is created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I am after is, to send information to our employees regardless of them having put information into their own list. These two things should be separated. One list (employees to HQ) is employees giving HQ information on what they have done with some customers. The other way around (which I am after), is for HQ to inform employees on potential leads for their customers. So we can tell employee X that he can sell some further products to customer Y. Does that make sense?
/Steffen

Comment: ..the user should be able, when loggin into sharepoint, to see the leads we give to them on their frontpage or by clicking on a specific link.